# How to add data on a dictionary using different multiple user input inside a class?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a simple program that takes user `name` and `age` using user input. How can I store the data on dictionary and update the data if another user put new name and age. Here is my sample code. I don't know if I'm doing it right.

```
class Name:
    data = {}
    num_employee = 0

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        Name.num_employee += 1

    @classmethod
    def user_in(cls):
        name = input('Enter name: ')
        age = int(input('Enter age: '))
        return cls(name, age)

    def show(self):
        Name.data = {'name': self.name, 'age': self.age}
        return Name.data


employ = Name.user_in()
employ2 = Name.user_in()
print(Name.num_employee)
print(employ.show())
```

Comment: Your code looks like it would work. What do you mean "doing it right'? stackoverflow isn't a code review site. Your question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every instance of a `Name` class would be a person with name and age. Now i'm not getting if you're supposing an employee can have more than one name (and this is why you need a dictionary) or you simply need an object to collect information about every user.

If you want to mantain the `input` inside of the class move it to the constructor, that is `__init__` method.
I would use another object such as a `list` to collect the set of users.

I also added two method to the class `Person` allowing user to modify age and name with a new input.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = input('Enter name: ')
        self.age = int(input('Enter age: '))

    def show(self):
        data = {'name': self.name, 'age': self.age}
        return data

    def change_name(self):
        self.name = input('Update name: ')

    def change_age(self):
        self.age = int(input('Update age: '))

persons = []

employ = Person()
employ2 = Person()

# add employ to the list
persons.append(employ)
persons.append(employ2)

# to show information
print(len(persons)) # len of the list is the number of employees
print(employ.show())

# to change employ1 name you can do
employ.change_name()

# to change employ2 age do
employ2.change_age()
```